# Just with several values?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I want a Publisher similar to `Just` except it should emit multiple values, and then complete the stream.

Let's call it `JustSeveral`:

```
func fibonacci(_ number: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
  Future { ... }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

JustSeveral([293, 18, 104])
  .flatMap { fibonacci($0) }
  .sink { print($0) }
```

Is there a way to combine operators with `Just` to get the same thing, or do I need to build this Publisher myself?

Note: Any solution should be able to handle an arbitrary number of elements in the array, not just 3.

---

For example, if we had an [`uncollect` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523248/combine-uncollect-operator), this would be trivial:

```
Just([293, 18, 104])
  .uncollect { $0 }
  .flatMap { fibonacci($0) }
  .sink { print($0) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing `Combine` extends `Array` with a computed property called `publisher`, which returns a `Sequence<Array<Int>, Never>`, which is a `Publisher`. So you can just do:

```swift
[293, 18, 104]
    .publisher
    .flatMap { fibonacci($0) }
    .sink { print($0) }
```

However, Apple's API documentation blows chunks, and I don't think there's a page that documents `Array.publisher`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing. I found some documentation here: https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-sequence

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: You should use the [built-in `.publisher` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67523663/35690).

---

**Original answer**:

One solution is to [make the publisher wait until there is a subscription and then emit values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62141356/35690):

```
public struct JustSeveral<Value>: Publisher {
  public init(_ outputs: [Value]) {
    self.outputs = outputs
  }

  public var outputs: [Value]

  public typealias Output = Value
  public typealias Failure = Never

  public func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Downstream.Input == Output, Downstream.Failure == Failure {
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Value, Never>()
    subject
      .subscribe(subscriber)

    outputs.forEach { subject.send($0) }
    subject.send(completion: .finished)
  }
}
```

Although this works, I don't know if it's the best solution since it only emits values upon a subscription. I'm not certain that that is how `Just` works.